# Django many-to-many relationships: prevailing naming convention

Tags: python, django

I am hoping to hear from some people with experience developing Django sites as part of some sort of team.

What is the naming convention most commonly seen for many-to-many relationships?  Do most people stick with the `entry_set` default, or is it more common and easier to use a more symmetrical `related_name='entries'` approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_set` suffix indicates that the attribute is a manager rather than a model, and should be retained in order to minimize confusion.

Comment: some other frameworks automatically pluralize things.  Django doesn't do that.  There's no reason to assume that `class Ox` should be pluralized as "oxs" since that's `"%ss" % Ox.__name__.lower()`, nor is it sound to reason that "bovine_table" is the correct pluralization either, even if the underlying persistence uses that name.

Comment: So the `related_name` should be avoided altogether?

Comment: Whenever possible, yes. Obviously there will be circumstances in which it cannot be avoided, but in those cases the name should also end in `_set`.

Comment: @Withnail: "So the related_name should be avoided altogether"?  False.  You need it when there are multiple relationships among two classes and you need to distinguish among the relationships.  If you have exactly one relationship among classes, don't do anything beyond taking the defaults.